If a p-group is normal then can we say G is going to be a direct product of P
I recently came across a theorem that states that if G is a finite group and every p-group of G is normal then G is isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow p subgroups. To prove this we use that in this case elements from different Sylow subgroups commute. Now in the abelian case (ie the $\mathbb{Z}$ module case) every subgroup is a direct summand of G by the classification theorem.
So I was wondering if we could do something similar in the non abelian case using normality. My question is:
If G is a finite group and P is a normal Sylow p subgroup then does there exist $H\leq G$ such that $G\cong P\times H$.
I believe this statement is not true in general (but it is true if all of the Sylow p subgroups are normal iff G is nilpotent), so what are some conditions for this to hold. Also what if we replaced the direct with semidirect product ?

There is always a subgroup $H$ such that $G = P \rtimes H$ by the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem

So to find conditions to get direct product we should look for conditions to make the semidirect product direct (also do you have any references for the proof of this theorem)

It's a direct product if and only if the homomorphism defining the semidirect product is trivial I don't think there is much more to say.

"In the abelian case, every subgroup is a direct summand of $G$ by the classification theorem." This is false. The subgroup of order $2$ is not a direct summand of the cyclic group of order $4$.

A trivial counterexample to your question is $S_3$, where the Sylow $3$-subgroup is normal, but it cannot be written as $S_3=A_3\times C_2$.

Thanks for your examples. I realized I made a big mistake on the way I applied the classification theorem.
